# Scoping issue with AngularJS and Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an odd issue with my AngularJS tooltip directive that works with bootstrap. I'm trying to get it to display a dynamic variable that is set on the scope, however it is displaying the actual angular syntax that I placed in the title. Below is a bootply showing the issue working in multiple manners except for the tooltip.

If you hover, you see the title tip displaying correctly, in the text, you also see the value displayed correctly, however the black tooltip that appears above isn't.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Example code here: http://www.bootply.com/OpNbEaXmBP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the question after @Shaun pointed me in the right direction.

This is a really simple fix. Simply replace the "title" attribute with "data-original-title"

Answer (score 1):

The `title` attribute is used by bootstrap to pass content into it's implementation of the `tooltip()` function. This is working independently of AngularJS, so it doesn't get interpolated. The [AngularUI Bootstrap library](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) can be used to get around these issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I googled around and found the correct answer